# What does the initial ".\" do at the start of a VS project's OutDir?

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, path

I've opened a VCXPROJ file to change the directory paths, and in the `OutDir` XML parameter, the following is marked:

```
<OutDir>.\..\..\..\..\..\Bin\$(PlatformName)\$(MsvcVer)\$(ProjectName)\</OutDir>
```

I need to change it to something like this, but is it valid? Does it need the `.\` at the start of the path? What does it mean anyways?

```
<OutDir>Bin\$(PlatformName)\$(MsvcVer)\$(ProjectName)\</OutDir>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.\` references the current directory. You shouldn't need it.